# reload iframe and click button inside iframe as much as I want

Tags: javascript

```
window.onhashchange = function () {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            let frame = document.querySelector("body > iframe");
            if (frame !== null) {frame.replaceWith(frame);}
        }, 1000);
    }
//reload the iframe
var i = 0;
while (i < 100) {
    async function DStuff(){
        await document.querySelector("#Btn").click()
    }
    setTimeout(() => { DStuff() }, 3000)
    window.onhashchange();
    i++;
}
//click button
```

I want to refresh iframe and click button as much as I want. When I run this script it doesn't loop. Also the script should wait for a second after click the button.

Comment: You are basically setting 100 3 second timeouts at (almost) the same time, so each one will end at the same time and run `DStuff` 100 times 3 seconds later.

Comment: so how to run window.onhashchange after Dstuff?

Comment: I'm not good at javascript. Please help me solve my noob question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the loop and simply use a setInterval:

```
window.onhashchange = function () {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            let frame = document.querySelector("body > iframe");
            if (frame !== null) {frame.replaceWith(frame);}
        }, 1000);
    }
//reload the iframe

var i = 0;   
let myVar = setInterval(function(){ 
  i++;
  document.querySelector("#Btn").click();
  window.onhashchange();
  if (i === 100) {
    clearInterval(myVar);
  }
},3000);
```

The above waits for 3 seconds until it clicks again while it stops after reaching 100 clicks.
Needless to say, the iFrame must be on the same domain, otherwise it won't be accessible due to cross-site restriction.

Comment: It gives me Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null. I think It doesn't get button because It tries to click button until page is loaded.

Comment: It worked just fine during my tests. Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jcyzeh1d/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a different time delay between the reload and the click, you can use two functions that recursively call each other, with a count to stop the loop:

```js
var totalIterations = 0;

function clickButton() {
  console.log("clickButton called")
  
  // Your Click-button code here
  //document.querySelector("#Btn").click()
  
  // In 1 second, call the reload frame function
  setTimeout(reloadFrame, 1000)
}

function reloadFrame() {
  console.log("reloadFrame called")
  
  // Your Reload-frame code here:
  //let frame = document.querySelector("body > iframe");
  //if (frame !== null) { frame.replaceWith(frame); }
  
  // If we haven't run 100 times yet, run the click button in 3 seconds
  if (totalIterations < 100) {
    setTimeout(clickButton, 3000)
    totalIterations++
  }
}

// Call the function to start
clickButton()
```